# How to apply elbow method on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, k-means

I want to apply the elbow method to determine the number of K clusters from the below dataframe (df) sample with 31 rows and 5 columns.

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
0.54,0.68,0.46,0.98,-2.14
0.52,0.44,0.19,0.29,30.44
1.27,1.15,1.32,0.60,-161.63
0.88,0.79,0.63,0.58,-49.52
1.39,1.15,1.32,0.41,-188.52
0.86,0.80,0.65,0.65,-45.27
```

I have tried the below which I found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-algorithms-part-9-k-means-example-in-python-f2ad05ed5203.

```
def elbow_K():

    wcss = [] 
    for i in range(1, 11):
        
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', max_iter=200, n_init=10, random_state=0)
        kmeans.fit(df)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
        plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
        plt.title('Elbow Method')
        plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
        plt.ylabel('WCSS')
        plt.show()
```

However, I get the error message 'ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct after `wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)`, it's correct in the linked article. Move the plotting code out of the `for` loop. You can't compute more than 6 clusters with only 6 samples in your dataset. Change the ranges to `range(1,7)` for your example data.

Comment: My silly mistake. Thanks so much for pointing it out

Comment: To clarify the error specifically (might help you diagnose if a similar thing happens again): because you have the plotting code inside the loop, in the first iteration of `plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)`, `wcss` has only one value. So when you try to plot, you have 10 x values and only 1 y value

Comment: Thanks G. Anderson. Well explained.